# Method for calculating the final score of fields with type of None

Tags: django, wagtail

Help me please figure out how to correctly check the value of the fields and draw up a total score of goals. The problem is that the final estimate is calculated by the `pre_save` method. And model has first half time of match, second half time of match and shootout score. User can just update the first halftime score and save that model in this case `pre_save` will take this value, add it to total score and ignore second halftime and shootout. But after second halftime of match, User have to update the score of second halftime and then `pre_save` method will calculate this two values (first and second) and ignore shootout and so one. I hope you will understand what I will achieve. Here is my model:

```
class GroupstageTournamentModel(ClusterableModel):
    #Score of TEAM 1
    team_1_first_halftime_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default=None, verbose_name='Resultat 1. HZ')
    team_1_first_halftime_point = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default=0, verbose_name='Punkte 1. HZ')
    team_1_second_halftime_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default=None, verbose_name='Resultat 2. HZ')
    team_1_second_halftime_point = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default=0, verbose_name='Punkte 2. HZ')
    team_1_shootout_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default=None, verbose_name='Resultat Shootout')
    team_1_shootout_point = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default=0, verbose_name='Schootout Punkte')
    team_1_total_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default=0, verbose_name='Resultat Total')
    team_1_total_points = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default=0, verbose_name='Punkte Total')

    #Score of TEAM 2
    team_2_first_halftime_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default=None, verbose_name='Resultat 1. HZ')
    team_2_first_halftime_point = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default=0, verbose_name='Punkte 1. HZ')
    team_2_second_halftime_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default=None, verbose_name='Resultat 2. HZ')
    team_2_second_halftime_point = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default=0, verbose_name='Punkte 2. HZ')
    team_2_shootout_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default=None, verbose_name='Resultat Shootout')
    team_2_shootout_point = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default=0, verbose_name='Schootout Punkte')
    team_2_total_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default=0, verbose_name='Resultat Total')
    team_2_total_points = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default=0, verbose_name='Punkte Total')

    @receiver(pre_save, sender='tournament.GroupstageTournamentModel')
    def my_callback(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
        # Point for first half time
        if not (instance.team_1_first_halftime_score is None and instance.team_2_first_halftime_score is None):
            if instance.team_1_first_halftime_score > instance.team_2_first_halftime_score:
                instance.team_1_first_halftime_point += 2
        elif not (instance.team_1_first_halftime_score is None and instance.team_2_first_halftime_score is None):
            if instance.team_2_first_halftime_score > instance.team_1_first_halftime_score:
                instance.team_2_first_halftime_point += 2
        elif not (instance.team_1_first_halftime_score is None and instance.team_2_first_halftime_score is None):
            if instance.team_1_first_halftime_score == instance.team_2_first_halftime_score:
                instance.team_2_first_halftime_point += 1
                instance.team_1_first_halftime_point += 1
        # Point for second half time
        if not (instance.team_1_second_halftime_score is None and instance.team_2_second_halftime_score is None):
            if instance.team_1_second_halftime_score > instance.team_2_second_halftime_score:
                instance.team_1_second_halftime_point += 2
        elif not (instance.team_1_second_halftime_score is None and instance.team_2_second_halftime_score is None):
            if instance.team_2_second_halftime_score > instance.team_1_second_halftime_score:
                instance.team_2_second_halftime_point += 2
        elif not (instance.team_1_second_halftime_score is None and instance.team_2_second_halftime_score is None):
            if instance.team_1_second_halftime_score == instance.team_2_second_halftime_score:
                instance.team_2_second_halftime_point += 1
                instance.team_1_second_halftime_point += 1
        # Point for Shootout
        if not (instance.team_1_shootout_score is None and instance.team_2_shootout_score is None):
            if instance.team_1_shootout_score > instance.team_2_shootout_score:
                instance.team_1_shootout_point += 1
        elif not (instance.team_1_shootout_score is None and instance.team_2_shootout_score is None):
            if instance.team_2_shootout_score > instance.team_1_shootout_score:
                instance.team_2_shootout_point += 1
        elif not (instance.team_1_shootout_score is None and instance.team_2_shootout_score is None):
            if instance.team_1_shootout_score == instance.team_2_shootout_score:
                instance.team_1_shootout_point += 0
                instance.team_2_shootout_point += 0
        instance.team_1_total_score = instance.team_1_first_halftime_score + instance.team_1_second_halftime_score + instance.team_1_shootout_score
        instance.team_2_total_score = instance.team_2_first_halftime_score + instance.team_2_second_halftime_score + instance.team_2_shootout_score
        instance.team_1_total_points = instance.team_1_first_halftime_point + instance.team_1_second_halftime_point + instance.team_1_shootout_point
        instance.team_2_total_points = instance.team_2_first_halftime_point + instance.team_2_second_halftime_point + instance.team_2_shootout_point
```

I have created some calculation of first, second and shootout scores. I initially wanted to cut this part of the code, but maybe this will make even clearer what I'm going to do.

NOTE. Its easy to do if I define default values as 0, but in this case my `pre_save` method will add automatically 1 point to both teams because the match ended with a score of 0 0.

Current code returns `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'`
And I started to fix it but im not sure how to solve this problem.

Comment: Why can't the scores default to 0 like the points do?

Comment: Points will be updated to 1 if both teams have equal score

Comment: What does that have to do with my question? Why can't you give the score fields `default=0`?

Comment: that means match ended with the result 0 0 and points will be updated to 1 for both teams

Comment: I could give the default value 0. But then I have to change my calculation condition and actually score can be 0-0 or 0-15 or as many as you like. And this makes the calculation difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following and it works. But any constructive criticism is welcome.

```
    # Total score calculation Team 1
    if not (instance.team_1_first_halftime_score is None):
        if instance.team_1_first_halftime_score >= 0:
            instance.team_1_total_score = instance.team_1_first_halftime_score
            if not (instance.team_1_second_halftime_score is None):
                if instance.team_1_second_halftime_score >= 0:
                    instance.team_1_total_score = instance.team_1_first_halftime_score + instance.team_1_second_halftime_score
                    if not (instance.team_1_shootout_score is None):
                        if instance.team_1_shootout_score >= 0:
                            instance.team_1_total_score = instance.team_1_first_halftime_score + instance.team_1_second_halftime_score + instance.team_1_shootout_point
    # Total score calculation Team 2
    if not (instance.team_2_first_halftime_score is None):
        if instance.team_2_first_halftime_score >= 0:
            instance.team_2_total_score = instance.team_2_first_halftime_score
            if not (instance.team_2_second_halftime_score is None):
                if instance.team_2_second_halftime_score >= 0:
                    instance.team_2_total_score = instance.team_2_first_halftime_score + instance.team_2_second_halftime_score
                    if not (instance.team_2_shootout_score is None):
                        if instance.team_2_shootout_score >= 0:
                            instance.team_2_total_score = instance.team_2_first_halftime_score + instance.team_2_second_halftime_score + instance.team_2_shootout_point
```